# php - Create array from an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this

```
array (size=1)
  45 => 
    object(stdClass)[37]
      public 'term_id' => string '45' (length=2)
      public 'name' => string 'Appointments' (length=12)
      public 'slug' => string 'appointments' (length=12)
      public 'term_group' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'term_taxonomy_id' => string '48' (length=2)
      public 'taxonomy' => string 'tribe_events_cat' (length=16)
      public 'description' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'parent' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'count' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'object_id' => string '625' (length=3)
   46 => 
    object(stdClass)[37]
      public 'term_id' => string '46' (length=2)
      public 'name' => string 'Appointmentx' (length=12)
      public 'slug' => string 'appointmentx' (length=12)
      public 'term_group' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'term_taxonomy_id' => string '48' (length=2)
      public 'taxonomy' => string 'tribe_events_cat' (length=16)
      public 'description' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'parent' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'count' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'object_id' => string '626' (length=3)
```

I would like to strip only `term_id` from that array and `merge` it like this

```
array(45,46,...);
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the keys also contain the IDs, you could use [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/array_keys):

```
$ids = array_keys($array);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$ids = array();

foreach($array as $object)
{
    $ids[] = $object->termId;
}
```